# Multi-Part HTML Form Validating Only Some Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I have this multi-part HTML form... I know it is a bit messy! I am working on it!

I want the validation to work but only work on the inputs that are not disabled. I want to make it so on the dropdowns when the text inputs are not disabled, it checks them but when they are disabled, they don't be checked!

How?

```html
    <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'admin', 'myphpadmin', 'tests');
        $qm = "Select Name From options Where `Type` = 'Merchant'";
        $merchant = mysqli_query($conn, $qm);
        $qt = "Select Name From options Where `Type` = 'Type'";
        $type = mysqli_query($conn, $qt);
        $qs = "Select Name From options Where `Type` = 'Source'";
        $source = mysqli_query($conn, $qs);
        $qsub = "Select Name From options Where `Type` = 'Sub'";
        $sub = mysqli_query($conn, $qsub);
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<form id="regForm" action="multi.php">
  <h1>Add Transaction</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Details
    <p><input placeholder="Description" oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" class='form-control' name="description"></p>
    <p><input oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" name="date" type='date' class='form-control'></p>
    <p><input placeholder='Amount' oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" name="amount" type='number' step='0.01' class='form-control'></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Merchant
    <p>
    <select oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" onchange='merch(this.value)' name="merchant" class='form-control'>
    <option value='' disable selected hidden>Select Merchant</option>
                        <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($merchant)){
                            foreach($row as $val){
                                echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$val'>$val</option>\n";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
    <option value='other'>Other</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type='text' name='om'  class='form-control omerch' placeholder='Other Merchant' disabled></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='am' class='form-check-input omerch' id='om' disabled><label for='om' >&nbspAdd To Merchants List?</label></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Type
     <p>
    <select oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" onchange='checktype(this.value)' name="type" class='form-control'>
    <option value='' disable selected hidden>Select Type</option>
                        <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type)){
                            foreach($row as $val){
                                echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$val'>$val</option>\n";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
    <option value='other'>Other</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type='text' name='ot'  class='form-control otype' placeholder='Other Type' disabled></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='at' class='form-check-input otype' id='ot' disabled><label for='ot' >&nbspAdd To Types List?</label></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Sub: 
<p>
    <select oninput="this.classList.remove('invalid')" onchange='checksub(this.value)' name="sub" class='form-control'>
    <option value='' disable selected hidden>Select Sub-Type</option>
                        <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub)){
                            foreach($row as $val){
                                echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$val'>$val</option>\n";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
    <option value='other'>Other</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type='text' name='os'  disabled class='form-control otype' placeholder='Other Sob' ></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='as' class='form-check-input osub' id='ot' disabled><label for='ot' >&nbspAdd To Subs List?</label></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>
<script>
        function merch(value){
        console.log(value);
        if(value == 'other'){
        $('.omerch').removeAttr('disabled');
        console.log('enabled')
        }
        else{
            $('.omerch').attr('disabled','disabled');
            console.log('disabled')
            $('input[type="checkbox"].omerch').attr('checked', false);
            $('input[type="text"].omerch').val('');
        }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I used `input:enabled`, `input:not(:disabled)`... Nothing worked!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just change one line and you can do this with JS itself rather than with your selector:

```
if (y[i].value == "")
```

to

```
if (y[i].value == "" && !y[i].disabled) {
```

Basically we say, is it blank and not (`!`) disabled.

Or if you do want to do it with CSS selectors it is

`input:not([disabled])` as `disabled` is an attribute and you need to use the attribute selector (`[]`).

Also you are using `getElementByTagName` - use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead as otherwise you are limited in the CSS you can use (Tag Name is for the element type such as `input`, `button` etc. so you can't use CSS selectors there).

### Full Validator Code JS way

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    ///////////////////////////////////CHANGED HERE////////////////////////////
    // If a field is empty and NOT disabled...
    if (y[i].value == "" && !y[i].disabled) {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

### Full Validator code CSS way

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  ///////////////////////////////////CHANGED HERE////////////////////////////
  y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input:not([disabled])");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

### A quick note

You may want to look into the `:valid` psuedo selector. It has the added benefit that you get some native checks for validation if you give the input a `type` attribute. It will also be `invalid` if you have an empty field provided you use the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute.

I have stolen the example from the MSDN page and added it below to show you how easy it can make life, not a single line of JS there.

You could then query your inputs with `input:valid` and `input:invalid` within your JavaScript so it makes life easier there too.

That gives you a good grounding and a nice fallback incase your JS fails for any reason, but [JavaScript is still useful to improve the accessibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888467/2702894)

Finally if you do decide to use the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo selectors and still want to perform some custom validation on top you can use the [`setCustomValidity` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) so you can rely on them solely (not a lot of people seem to know about this!)

```css
input + span {
  position: relative;
}

input + span::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 5px;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input:invalid + span::before {
  content: '✖';
  color: red;
}

input:valid + span::before {
  content: '✓';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Feedback form</legend>

        <p>Required fields are labelled with "required".</p>
        <div>
          <label for="fname">First name: </label>
          <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" required>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="lname">Last name: </label>
          <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" required disabled>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email address (): </label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div><button>Submit</button></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: The `js` way doesn't work! If I don't put a value for the select's it still lets me through! If I do it also lets me through! I had already tried this way... Any other ideas?

Comment: Your question does on about `<input>`s not `<select>`s :-P `input` will not grab `select`s as they are different elements. Do you want to turn the code into a JSFiddle then and I will help, there is far too much code in that example to mentally debug and sift through, need to be able to play with it live as from what I can tell you don't even check the validity of the `<select>`s at the moment and you haven't included the `checkSub` function (whatever that is?).

Comment: will the CSS only way work with bootstrap validation classes?

Comment: I can try the jsfiddle but look at my comment above

Comment: What I showed should work for `input` elements that are disabled.

Comment: The second example "Full Validator code CSS way" will work with bootstrap as it is only looking at the `disabled` attribute and does not care about classes, but you will still need to add the `.invalid` CSS like you currently do for styling. The `A quick note` section would not work without setting the styles to look for `:valid` ad `:invalid` so perhaps ignore that bit for now.

Comment: Let me try the bootstrap!

Comment: I take it you made some meaningful progress now? Did the above work for your inputs once you fixed the selects? Any issues let me know and I will see if I can help. Good luck with the project(s)!

Comment: Yes! I used the first solution but just changed the: `y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");` To: `y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input, select");` Thanks!